# Editing mysql data of clicked row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My mysql data is extracted from the database

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "",database);

echo"<table border='1'>";
echo"
 <tr>
  <td>id</td>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
 </tr>";

$sql="select id,a,b from person";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die("Error : $sql");

 while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo"<tr tr onclick=\"location='?id=$row[id]'\">
  <td>{$row['id']}</td>
  <td>{$row['a']}</td>
  <td>{$row['b']}</td>
  </tr>";
 }
echo"</table>";
```

And with the

```
onclick=\"location='?id=$row[id]
```

I wish to enter a form to edit the whole row of the clicked id. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For general,
you can use a **bootstrap modal** for showing up the form and open the modal when user click in a row in the table. In my opinion, this is look like your homework, you show google it and read the document first.